# Appending Button not working

Tags: javascript, button, append

```
function story1(){
var t=document.createElement('p');
t.innerHTML = "You wake up from your sleep in a half daze to hear noises of screams outside your bedroom window. You stumble over there to see what is the matter. You decide it's a good idea to grab your"+' <i onclick=addSword()> '+" sword "+' </i> '+"as you take the "+' <i onclick=story2()> '+" stairs. "+'</i>';
document.getElementById("story").appendChild(t);
}

function story2(){
var t = document.createElement('p');
t.innerHTML = "You realize that the door is locked and need to break the code in order to go outside." +' <i id="one" onclick=addOne()> '+ num1 +'</i>'+' <i id="two" onclick=addTwo()> '+ num2+'</i>'+' <i id="three" onclick=addThree()> '+ num3 +'</i>';
document.getElementById("story").appendChild(t);
var b = document.createElement('input');
b.type = 'button';
b.value = 'Check Code';
b.onclick = checkCode();
document.getElementById("story").appendChild(b);
}
```

In short these two functions are where my issue lies. I'm trying to append a button inside of a div to check to see if the code is broken. The coding for `checkCode` is working as is.

The issue is, that `checkCode()` is actually working when stairs in clicked instead of the button. I've tried `b.on('click', checkCode())` and `b.setAttribute('onclick', checkCode())`.

Maybe I'm not coding the button right, but tutorials and reading answers to similar problems can only get me so far! (lol)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the result of the function `checkCode` to the handler/attribute in stead of the function reference. You are invoking it.

Try:

```
b.onclick = checkCode;
```

or

```
b.on('click', checkCode);
```

You need to set the reference of the function to the handler. setting it with `()` will invoke the function then and there and hence you see the behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe all it was were those stupid brackets messing me up.